# Error while queueing an email with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, rails-activejob

When sending an email with sidekiq as a queue using **deliver_later**. I'm getting this error:

> ActiveJob::DeserializationError: Error while trying to deserialize
>   arguments: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

The exact same email is sent without any problem using **deliver_now** in the console.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **RACK_ENV** environment variable is needed (besides RAILS_ENV).

So, for production:

```
export RACK_ENV=production
```

Answer (score -1):

`fe_sendauth: no password supplied` is an auth error from postgresql. When you enqueue a job which receives as a parameter a model it will serialize the object using globalid (something like "gid://app/Person/1") and when it tries to run the job it will deserialize the job (will basically do `Person.find(1)`). From the server where you have your workers running you cannot connect to the database with the given credentials.